# Facebook OpenGraph does not see my meta tags

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Can anybody help me to find out why Facebook OpenGraph does not see my meta tags:

https://www.scrolltravel.com/test/fb_og.html

Thanks

Comment: Where are your programming attempts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTTP  RESPONSE CODE is 0 ????  instead of 200 ??
This can be a real problem.

Please use the Facebook Debugger and fix all displayed problems.

You have a SSL error - maybe this is stopping facebook to analyse the tags. Otherwise the tags look fine.

```
SSL Error
Can't validate SSL Certificate. Either it is self-signed (which will cause browser warnings) or it is invalid.
Curl-Error
Curl-Error: 60 (SSL_CACERT)
```

check the tags here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scrolltravel.com%2Ftest%2Ffb_og.html

Comment: I know this tool. But what is the reason? Image and other values are provided explicitly. Is it due to self-signed SSL?

Comment: Probably.  Please get a free but BUT REAL cert   and try again.

Comment: The http response code is =  0 !!! ?" according  to the fb debugger  - pls fix this.

Comment: I use ZeroSSL RSA Domain Secure Site CA provided for free by Hostinger.com - it should be real. I have used other free SSL before, but it expired. Maybe switch to new SSL did not work. But you are wright - something wrong with SSL - that may be the reason why Facebook Sharing Debugger shows nothing after click on "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL". Strange that I get no browser warning when visiting website.

Comment: I found good link about my error "
Curl error: 60 (SSL_CACERT)": https://victorlava.com/how-to-fix-curl-60-ssl_cacert-cant-validate-ssl-certificate/ I asked to help my hosting provider.

Comment: now it works.   response code is 20x, ssl error is gone fields are recognized now.  even the image is displayed. :-)   pls mark answer as accepted.   (possibly it also helped that we have scraped it - you never know exactly what fb does )

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.scrolltravel.com%2Ftest%2Ffb_og.html

Comment: Yes, hosting provider solved problem with SSL. Thank you, Alexander.